# Can I replace and read simultaneously?

Tags: php, file, file-io

I have a file and I don't wanna take a copy from this file.

so I'd like  to replace and read simultaneously in PHP5;

In my head , The code will be the following :

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('text', 'rw');
while (!feof($fp)) {
  $line = fgets($fp);
  $line = "CONVERTED";
  fprintf($fp,$line);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: why to read at all? I see no sense in your question

Comment: umm. sorry for my poor english . I can't explain clearly. but . I wanna change a file withought any tmp file.

Comment: what's so evil in tmp files? why you're trying to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can conceptually, but it will be difficult if you are replacing content with content of a different length.

`fgets` and `fprintf` work by working with a file pointer. The pointer is basically where you are in the file. Both using `fgets` and `fprintf` will advance that pointer. Consider this representation of a short file (`>` is the pointer) right after it has been opened:

```
>First line
 Second line
 Third line
```

Then you run your first `fgets`, which reads the line and moves the pointer:

```
 First line
>Second line
 Third line
```

Now if you try to write to the file, it will write where the pointer is; overwriting the content. So say you changed "First line" to "Foobar", and try to write immediately following the `fgets` call (as in your code), this will be the result:

```
 First line
 Foobar> line
 Third line
```

Note that the pointer is now in the middle of the line.

If you however rewind the pointer before you use `fprintf`, it will print in the right place:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('text', 'rw');
while (!feof($fp)) {
  $line = fgets($fp);
  fseek($fp, -strlen($line), SEEK_CUR);
  // length has to be identical to string you replaced
  $line = "FoobarLine"; 
  fprintf($fp,$line);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Note that this will NOT work if your replacement lines differ in size from the original, as it will then overwrite data it should not, or start reading at the wrong place.

---

Better solutions would be:

- If the file is small enough; use `file` to load it line by line, modify the array to your liking, and overwrite it using `file_put_contents(implode("\n", $array)`.
- Simply use a temporary file. Not a big deal.